# How can I kill those nasty noximanders in the blacksmith's cellar?

Tags: eschalon-book-2

In the very back of the blacksmith's basement *(Who am I kidding it was a dungeon!)* I ran into these horrible creatures that bite you and leave you to die in seconds from their poison. Any ideas on how to properly kill them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to lure them out one by one and close the gate that originally kept them in while they are under it. Is this the best solution? I don't know, but it sure was awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The noximanders can be a real pain for a starting character. One (lame) solution is to concentrate on one of them, and once it's killed flee, rest, and return. If I remember correctly monsters regenerate hitpoints with time, but are not resurrected.

Alternatively, you can shoot at them from a distance, then flee once they get close. Or try in general to keep your distance.

And finally, the best advice is simply to come back later. The Eschalon games allow you to just go wherever you please - if one place is too difficult, just go elsewhere and come back later. It's been a while since I played Book I, but I just played Book II and I returned to already-visited dungeons many times.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from JSDarkwood's walkthrough at [gamefaqs.com](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/936836-eschalon-book-i/faqs):

> **Noximander**
>
> A large green amphibian.
>
> HP: 35
>   XP: 45
>   To Hit: 10 (80%)
>   Damage: 7
>   Armor: 11
>   Special: Poison
>
> Noximanders are most likely the first poisonous creature you encounter and are tough compared to the enemies around them at first.  Ranged Attacks are best against them because poison can be deadly early on when you are unlikely to have regular access to Detox spells or potions.  The best you can do is rest and/or cure yourself until the poison goes away.